# How to update table x using conditions found in table y in sqlLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables:
Customer:

```
Client_name     varchar(20),
Client_id       int,
Insurance_years int, 
last_value      decimal(10,2),
new_value       decimal(10,2);
```

Accident:

```
Client_id int,
Accident_year int;
```

I need to do NEW_VALUE=LAST_VALUE+(0.08*LAST_VALUE), a simple 8% increase for every **CLIENT_ID** in table **Customer** that had **ACCIDENT_YEAR > 2000**

and

For the Client's that **accident_year < 2000** ***and insurance_year > 6*** I need to give them a 10% discount of **LAST_VALUE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by filtering in the `where` clause:

```
update customer
    set NEW_VALUE = LAST_VALUE + (0.08 * LAST_VALUE)
    where client_id in (select a.client_id from accident a);
```

I might phrase this more simply as:

```
update customer
    set NEW_VALUE = LAST_VALUE * 1.08 
    where client_id in (select a.client_id from accident a);
```

Comment: what does the **a** in (select **a**.client_id from accident **a**);  mean ?

Comment: `accident a` creates a table alias, which can save typing if you need to refer to the table. But in this case, the subquery could be simply written as `(select client_id from accident)`.